# Centering React-Grid-Gallery ReactJS Library

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I've started to use [react-grid-gallery](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-grid-gallery), and it seems to be perfect for what I need it for. The only issue I have with it is that I can't seem to figure out how to actually center it. Below is how it's displayed on the screen:[image: Here is what the page looks like:]

I can't seem to adjust the margins of the gallery or center it at all.

```
class Testimonials extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <h2>See what people are saying...</h2>
                <body className="testimonial-body">
                    <p>"Dependable, trustworthy, and expert workmanship all 
                       describe Kevin and his business.  
                       He completely transformed our condo, painting it from top to 
                       bottom, among other projects.
                       Not only does he do excellent work, but he's a 
                       pleasure to have in your home. For any future projects, 
                       there's no one we'd rather have than Kevin." 
                       <span class="testimonial-signature"> - Doug and Sue &sdot; Brookfield, WI</span>
                    </p>
                </body>
                <center><Gallery images={doug_and_sue_images}/></center>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: you can acheive the same thing using material ui

Comment: Look at how these examples are done: https://github.com/benhowell/react-grid-gallery/tree/master/examples , You can acieve that using css. Also I noticed that your <Gallery /> out of your body element,

Comment: @Blasanka you're right, that should be in the body. I was just moving it around to see if I got different results. Ideally I should be able to control it with body css.

Answer (score 0):

`<center>` is deprecated - use css. The following is the standard way of cetnering horizontally in the viewport -

```
Gallery { margin: 0 auto;}
```

One thing I am not sure about is you are using a  element - should this be a div with a class of "gallery"?

or put it in a div that has the centered styling

```
<div class="gallery-wrapper">
   <Gallery images={doug_and_sue_images}/>
</div>

// css
.gallery-wrapper {
  text-align: center;
}
.gallery-wrapper Gallery {
  max-width: 80%; // or whatever you want
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the replay - I can't seem to get that to work. I don't seem to have control over the gallery itself.